# jquery script only works during page load

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

I've got a strange problem I can't seem to figure out:
I'm working on a Joomla template which is supposed to feature a button that fade/toggle's another layer.
The used script is super-simple and common:

Button: `<button style="text-align: center;" id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn_daytours" data-ap-original-font-size="18px">Click here</button>`

Layer:`<div class="tour_calendar" style="display: none;"><div class="moduletable span12">...</div></div>`

Script: // TOGGLE LAYER

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#tour_calendar").fadeToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
});
```

...and there seems nothing wrong with that setup but the problem is that the script only works WHILE THE PAGE IS LOADING. Once it's completely loaded it doesn't respond anymore.
I've tried to put the function in different places in the code but the problem persists.
I'm not really a coder and firebug doesn't show any conflicts so any hint would be appreciated.
Please try for yourself: https://biz211.inmotionhosting.com/~blackb78/blackbear2017/

and thanx in advance

Comment: Look in your console. `$ is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! That error seems to refer to the paralax though, which is working fine. Sorry if I misunderstand...like I wrote: Im not a coder ;-)

Comment: if I put any jquery code in the console on your site, it tells me `$ is not a function`.

Comment: Does that mean jquery is not properly loaded?
This is in the template as well:     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

I wonder why it's working while the page loads though...

Comment: that's right. It might be something with including jquery, jquery no conflict, and jquery migrate.

Comment: Bang-on Michael!!! Un-setting media/jui/js/jquery.min.js did the trick. Having a beer on you now ;-)

Comment: Actually `.load()` has changed become ajax processing function, so of course your script will produce malfunction. See this http://api.jquery.com/load/ and see my answer below. Hope this is the problem. :)

Comment: @Sawyer right on! cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).load(function() { ... });` is DEPRECATED and `.load()` has even changed function become ajax processing function.

Try to change to:

`$(window).on('load',function() { ... });`

Comment: That will work too :D The only difference is that `$(document).ready(function()` occur when page has opened, while `$(window).on('load',function()` is occur when all page's DOM elements are loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$(window).load(function() {});` and just put this code directly.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#tour_calendar").fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
    return false;
});
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no element with id "tour_element". Instead there is an element with class "tour_element". So I would suggest changing `$("#tour_calendar").fadeToggle();` to `$(".tour_calendar").fadeToggle();`.

Comment: Thanx Harshit! Messing with the code around ...but the class is what I ended up using ...of course now the paralax is not working properly anymore LOL Anyways, it's a script-conflict I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$("#tour_calendar").fadeToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
```

then

```
$(window).load(function(){
$( "#button" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

if you want some other place example,

```
$(document).bind(function()){
 $( "#button" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

Any other place just use following code inside the function

```
$( "#button" ).trigger( "click" );
```

thats it